# PHP How to generate new file txt per day with data

Tags: php

I've created data collection for a specific txt file. I need the script to separate records per days.

For example: today is 100 data and i need have a log16Jan.txt file, tomorrow we have 52 data and i need have a log17Jan.txt file?

How i can do that?

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];



    $tekst = "Name: $namee \r\n";

    $uchwyt = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    fwrite($uchwyt, $tekst);
    fclose($uchwyt);
    header("Location: http://#/complete.html");
    ?>
```

Comment: You mean you want `log.txt` to be named as today's date?

Comment: is there a special reason as to why you're not using a database instead? doing this with text files are a lot of work.

Comment: `$namee` btw, is an undefined variable.

Comment: you've too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: you need to stop taking advantage of people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date using the [`date()` function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and add it to the file name, like this:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tekst = "Name: $name \r\n";

// Adding today's date to the log file
$uchwyt = fopen("log".date("dM").".txt", "a");

fwrite($uchwyt, $tekst);
fclose($uchwyt);
header("Location: http://#/complete.html");
```

Comment: Mehdi Bounya Can you tell me how to make the numbering of these records?

Comment: What do you mean by numbering? and what records?

Comment: 1. Name:Adam 2. Name: Matt 3. Name: Mike ect :)

Comment: Your code doesn't allow such things and you need to consider doing another approach, your current code is for a small tool used by 1 or 2 people for a small task.

Comment: sooo i can;t use php count for this ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with PHP, the problem is with your code, you are getting input from a POST input and outputting it into a file, how are you going to count data? you may want to learn PHP or look for a tutorial to achieve your task.

Comment: Mehdi Bounya  THANKS FOR HELP!

Comment: @Rafał You are welcome, if you find this answer helpful feel free to approve it, and also your previous questions are not closed, make sure you approve the right answer as people invested time helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `date()` function.

And since you are creating log files you should consider using a log file name that will sort natively in date order in a directory listing.  This will make it easier to find a specific log file in a large listing of files.  It will also give you more log file cleanup/removal options.

For example:

```
// 2018-01-16-log.txt
$logFilename = date("Y-m-d") . "-log.txt";

$uchwyt = fopen($logFilename, "a");
```

UPDATE: per your request about adding a line number before each log line, there are many ways to do this and some depend on your server environment (Linux/Windows).  You could read each line from the log and keep a counter.  Or you could use a server utility, like Linux `wc` (Word Count).  Here's one way to do it:

```
<?php
        // 2018-01-16-log.txt
        $logFilename = date("Y-m-d") . ".log";

        echo "Log file = $logFilename\n";

        if (! file_exists($logFilename)) {
                $count = 0;
        } else {
                // use Linux wc utility
                $count = system("wc -l < $logFilename");

                $count = trim($count);
        }
        echo "Lines = '$count'\n";

        $name = $_POST['name'];

        if (! $name) {
                $name = "NONE";
        }

        $tekst = "$count. Name: $name \n";

        $uchwyt = fopen($logFilename, "a");

        fwrite($uchwyt, $tekst);

        fclose($uchwyt);
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to make the numbering of these records?  
1. Name:Adam 2. Name: Matt 3. Name: Mike ect :)

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff.  You should consider taking a PHP class.  But I did include an update to my answer above.